# What is this substance that looks like red sap on my cucumbers?

Tags: diagnosis, diseases, greenhouse, cucumbers, sap

I have this weird red sap on a few of my cucumbers. I was wondering if anyone has seen this before?

These cucumbers were grown in our conservatory in the back garden (facing south) in pots, grown up bamboo canes (not sure how helpful this information is)

[image: Very close up]

[image: A bit less close up]

Comment: I have now eaten a cucumber with a bit of this sap. Skinned it first, no signs under the skin and it tasted fine (: